# Cocos2d - running a block after a transition

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have this code:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:
 [CCTransitionProgressRadialCW transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:scene2]];
```

Is there a way to call a `CCCallBlock` after the transition is done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not certain about a call back, but i believe that cocos objects have a

```
-(void)onEnterTransitionDidFinish {
}
```

which you could use.

Comment: ok, I know, I was talking about running a block and I want to put the running code on the calling scene. I guess I will have to make a block myself on the other scene class.

Comment: aahh .. the only easy one i would see is to use the onExit method of the initial scene then ... but not a block still :)